# What is wrong with this PHP function?

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP function to query a database and return the complete result set but it's not working (I get no results). I'm new to PHP, am I using the function properly?

```
<?php

$sql = array(
    'user'     => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'server'   => '10.10.10.10', 
    'db'       => 'XE'
);

$conn = oci_connect($sql['user'], $sql['password'], $sql['server'].'/'.$sql['db']);

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error( htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR );
}

function db_query( $conn, $bindings, $query )
{
    $stmt = oci_parse( $conn, trim($query) );

    foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
        if ( strpos( $query, $key) ) {
            oci_bind_by_name( $stmt, $key, $value );
        }
    }

    oci_execute( $stmt );
    oci_fetch_all( $stmt, $data );
    oci_free_statement( $stmt );

    return $data;
}

$bindings = array();
$query    = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders';

echo db_query();

?>
```

Comment: Query some stuff using your own `var_dump(db_query($conn, $bindings, $query))`, what it says?

Comment: your `db_query` function expects 3 parameters but you call it with none

Comment: @pomeh But $conn, $bindings and $query are set. I guess I'm doing it wrong. Can you just post an example?

Comment: no they aren't in the function itself, since there are listed as arguments in the function definition, and PHP use function scope so all variables defined outside of a function are not accessible inside this function, unless you use the `global` keyword (which I would NOT recommend to use at all)

Comment: @user3973427 they are set *outside* the function. Pass them as parameters or make them globals

Comment: The variables `$bindings, $query` are set, yes, but need to _pass_ them to the function.  `echo db_query($conn, $bindings, $query);`

Comment: Note that `echo` here is going to print something like `'Array'` rather than any particular scalar value, since that is what `oci_fetch_all()` will return.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah I see. What should I use when I know the query will only ever return 1 row? I just want to get that value, as simply as possible.

Comment: @user3973427 If you are certain there should be only one row and you have PHP 5.4+, you may use something like `oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_NUM)[0]` to fetch and get the first `[0]` column.  However, while this is fine for a `COUNT(*)` query which is guaranteed to return one row, do not use it if the query may return zero rows, as that would place an array index `[0]` on a non-array return (false) from the function.  Safer to just call `oci_fetch_array()` and test for `false` then get the desired column by its index.

Comment: With what you have now, you could keep `oci_fetch_all()` and return like `return (is_array($data) && isset($data[0][0])) ? $data[0][0] : false;` to return the single value or false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Set your bindings
$bindings = array();
//Set your Query
$query    = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders';
//Fire it up and store the result in $data
$data = db_query( $conn, $bindings, $query );
//Dump $data to see whats inside
var_dump($data);
```

This should help you... 
If $data returns NULL, make sure the query is correct, the databasetable is filled with data and the database connection is successful.

Steps:

1. update your code
2. dump $data and check the result
3. check the databse connection
4. check the databasetable
5. have a drink...